# Error in importing dependencies on google cloud ML

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

While submittng a job on gogle cloud ML, I am getting an error where main training python file i.e. task.py is not able to import a function from a python script in util folder.

Generally, we write :
from util.xyz import abc

this is not getting called in the main task.py

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to one of two reasons:

(1) You may be missing an `__init__.py` in your module directory (or util subdirectory)

(2) You may need to import the module as trainer.util.xyz (assuming your overall module is called trainer)

Comment: __init__.py is already there in all modules and subdirectory also and I tried the second thing also ...its not working .